# Is there a simple way to rewrite this 3 line algorithm?

Tags: algorithms

There is a very simple algorithm step, part of a larger algorithm. I can't think of a simple way to put it in an algorithmic form!

#### The problem

> Given is:
>
> - a vector $a_t$ (such as $\{7, 4, 0, 10\}$),
> - an index $t'$ (such as $3$),
> - and a value $e$ (such as $5$).
>
> The aim is to "remove" a total amount of $e$ from
> the vector $a_t$ starting at index $t'$ and going backward.

#### My solution

First, here is a $\LaTeX$ code for the algorithm in the way I thought of, and below I explain it with an example.

> $ \begin{equation} \text{while } (e>0)\\ \qquad t^* = \max \{ t: a_t 
> > 0, t \le t' \}\\ \qquad \kappa \leftarrow a_{t^*}\\ \qquad a_{t^*} \leftarrow a_{t^*} - \min \{ a_{t^*}, e \}\\ \qquad e \leftarrow e - \kappa \\ \text{endwhile} \end{equation} $

In the first line of the algorithm I find the largest index of $t$ with non zero values before $t'$. In this case $t^*=2$. Then I set $\kappa = 4$ just to store. Then I update $a_2 = 4- \min\{4,5\} = 0$ and $e = 5-4=1$. Now I must remove $1$ from the previous entry of $a$. So I go back and do it from the first entry, *i.e.* $7$. Then the process exits.

#### The question

The algorithm I wrote for this simple subtraction seems too complicated. How do I rewrite it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to look for the largest non-zero entry with index $\le t'$. It is simpler to start directly from $t'$ and don't make distinctions whether or not the entries are zero.

So my solution is the following:

$
\begin{equation}\\
\text{while }(e>0 \text{ and } t'>0)\\
\qquad x \leftarrow \min\{a_{t'}, e\}\\
\qquad a_{t'} \leftarrow a_{t'} - x\\
\qquad e \leftarrow e - x\\ 
\qquad t' \leftarrow t' - 1\\
\text{endwhile}
\end{equation}
$